# Spring MVC: Request Scope, trying to update a Command Object with binder.setDisallowedFields

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3, spring-4, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have this Object

```
public class Deportista implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6229604242306465153L;

    private String id;
    ...

    @NotNull(message="{field.null}")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    ...

}
```

I have the following Controller's methods

```
@InitBinder(value="deportistaRegistrar")
public void registrarInitBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    logger.info(">>>>>>>> registrarInitBinder >>>>>>>>>>>>>");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/registrar.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String crearRegistrarFormulario(Model model){
    logger.info("crearRegistrarFormulario GET");
    Deportista deportista = new Deportista();
    model.addAttribute("deportistaRegistrar", deportista);
    return "deportista.formulario.registro";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/registrar.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String registrarPerson(@Validated @ModelAttribute("deportistaRegistrar") Deportista deportista, 
                              BindingResult result){

    logger.info("registrarPerson POST");
    logger.info("{}", deportista.toString());

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        logger.error("There are errors!!!!");

        for(ObjectError objectError : result.getAllErrors()){
            logger.error("Error {}", objectError);
        }

        return "deportista.formulario.registro";
    }

    logger.info("All fine!!!!");
    this.fakeMultipleRepository.insertDeportista(deportista);
    return "redirect:/manolo.htm";
}
```

Until here the Controller is able to create a form (GET) and submit (POST) a **new** *command* object, `Validation` code works well.

The problem is with the update.

I have the following:

```
@InitBinder(value="deportistaActualizar")
public void actualizarInitBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    logger.info(">>>>>>>> actualizarInitBinder >>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    binder.setDisallowedFields("id");
}
```

Observe I have `binder.setDisallowedFields("id")`

```
public String crearActualizarFormulario(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model){
    logger.info("crearActualizarFormulario GET");
    Deportista deportista = this.fakeMultipleRepository.findDeportista(id);
    model.addAttribute("deportistaActualizar", deportista);
    return "deportista.formulario.actualizacion";
}   

@RequestMapping(value="/{id}/actualizar.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String actualizarPerson(@Validated @ModelAttribute("deportistaActualizar") Deportista deportista, 
                           BindingResult result){

    logger.info("actualizarPerson POST");
    logger.info("{}", deportista.toString());

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        logger.error("There are errors!!!!");

        for(ObjectError objectError : result.getAllErrors()){
            logger.error("Error {}", objectError);
        }

        return "deportista.formulario.actualizacion";
    }

    logger.info("All fine!!!!");
    this.fakeMultipleRepository.updateDeportista(deportista);
    return "redirect:/manolo.htm";
}
```

The problem is:

- when the form or command has any error, the controller re-render the view and the form appear showing the error messages how is expected, **but without the ID value**

or

- if I try to update the object, of course keeping the id value, and without any error to simply proceed to update, it fails

The following appears in the Console:

```
- -------- createCollections ---------------
- >>>>>>>> actualizarInitBinder >>>>>>>>>>>>>
- Skipping URI variable 'id' since the request contains a bind value with the same name.
- actualizarPerson POST
- Deportista [id=null, nombre=Manuel, ...]
- There are errors!!!!
- Error Field error in object 'deportistaActualizar' on field 'id': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.deportistaActualizar.id,NotNull.id,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [deportistaActualizar.id,id]; arguments []; default message [id]]; default message [The field must be not empty]
```

The **id** is null. How I can around this problem keeping the **Request Scope**?

I have an alternate controller which is working with `@SessionAttributes` and all works perfect. But since is a huge risk if the user has many tabs open in the same web browser, one for create and other for updating, all is going to be very wrong. According with [Spring MVC + Session attributes and multiple tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10799908), request scope should be used instead of session scope. It has sense.

Sadly *seems* Spring is not going to fix this:
[@SessionAttributes doesn't work with tabbed browsing](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4160)

**Addition**

According with your suggestion, I have the following:

```
@ModelAttribute("deportistaActualizar")
public Deportista populateActualizarFormulario(@RequestParam(defaultValue="") String id){
    logger.info("populateActualizarFormulario - id: {}", id);
    if(id.equals(""))
        return null;
    else
        return this.fakeMultipleRepository.findDeportista(id);
}
```

Observe the method uses `@RequestParam`, my problem is how update that method to work when the URL to update has the following style
`http://localhost:8080/spring-utility/deportista/1/actualizar.htm`. There is no *param* in the URL, therefore `@RequestParam` is useless now.

I already have read the Spring Reference documentation:
[Using @ModelAttribute on a method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods)

**Second Addition**

Yes, you was right, and I did that yesterday, but I forget to share the following:

```
@ModelAttribute("deportistaActualizar")
public Deportista populateActualizarFormulario(@PathVariable(value="id") String id){
    logger.info("populateActualizarFormulario - id: {}", id);
    if(id.equals(""))
        return null;
    else
        return this.fakeMultipleRepository.findDeportista(id);
}
```

Since a `@ModelAttribute` is called always before by any `handler` method, the following URL fails `http://localhost:8080/spring-utility/deportista/registrar.htm`, the following appears on the page

```
HTTP Status 400 -
type Status report
message
description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

Of course because the URL does not contains the expected `id`. Therefore I can't create new records to later edit/see.

I can confirm, that for the following work:

- `http://localhost:8080/spring-utility/deportista/1/detalle.htm`
- `http://localhost:8080/spring-utility/deportista/1/actualizar.htm`

the id (1) is retrieved.

How I could resolve this?

Thank You

Comment: The problem is that you are using 2 methods which basically operate on the same object. However they don't share the object. As I also answered in the other question add a method annotated with `@ModelAttribtue` which retrieves the desired object based on the id. Basically remove the retrieval of the object from the get method and put it in a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute`.

Comment: Understood, but see the `Addition` section. Thank You.

Comment: Just place a `@PathVariable` on there almost all the annotation usable on a `@RequestMapping` method apply to `@ModelAttribute` methods.

Comment: Could you check the `Second Addition` section please? Thank You.

Comment: Currently there is no way to define a default or optional path variable. As a workaround you can create 2 controllers one for creating a new one, the other for updating existing ones.

Comment: That was I thought, the *worst* scenario. Just wondered how you around the problem about `@SessionAttributes` with the problem of "multiple tabs". Thank You.

Comment: I am going to create a JIRA issue (improvement) with Spring 4 & 4.1 out there, it should be fix it. Thanks by all Marten!

Comment: I have created two controllers, it works now. Thank You